# Subdomain for registered users

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

Is there any way to show each registered user's post in user side like http://mydomain.com/registered_username?  ie, if registered_username is a registered user, then his posts must be accessed by any normal users like  http://mydomain.com/registered_username

Answer (score 0):

```
function functionName(registered_username)
{
    window.location = "mydomain.com/?registered_username=" + registered_username;
}
```